# Merge Fields in the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework in ASP.NET and I have a class called Contacts and in it I have the following fields : Name , E- Mail and Phones. The field is a list Phones subclass type which has the following fields : PhoneNumber and Operator .

In Entity Framework can create , insert, change and delete normally in the database .

Now I need to export all contacts with your phone the first number from the list of phones to Json .

When I export the JSON looks like this .

```
[
  {
    " name " : " Name " ,
    "email" : " E- Mail"
    " phones" : [
      {
        " phonenumber " : " 000000000 "
        "operator " : "Operator "
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to join the fields of Contacts with Phones in the subclass
Entity Framework so I can export as well :

```
[
  {
    " name " : " Name " ,
    "email" : " E- Mail"
    " phonenumber " : " 000000000 "
    "operator " : "Operator "
  }
]
```

In SQLServer I can do this:

```
select
name
, email
, ( select top 1 phonenumber from phones where contact_id = contact.id )
, ( select top 1 operator from phones where contact_id = contact.id )
from contact
```

How do the Entity Framework to merge the fields to export
for Json as mentioned above ?

Use VB.NET but if not in vb can be in C # .

Comment: You could create a property and in the getter fetch the first phone and return its value.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using EntityFramework I'd do something else like this :

```
return Json(new
                        {
                            name = YourObject.Name,
                            email = YourObject.Email,
                            phonenumber = YourObject.Phones.PhoneNumber,
                            operator = YourObject.Operator 
                        });
```

Would that work for you ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've done that way, but gets bad specify each field. Imagine a table with over 30 fields. I'm trying to figure out a way to create a virtual table and add fields to then export to Json.

Comment: You're welcome, you could do it another way may be but as C# is strongly typed, this is the only idea I have for you. I don't know why you need this kind of export, but you could try with a little reflexion (it's powerful). Otherwise you can create an object with the desired fields and a constructor to make things simpler.